# How do I make a rig with one bone?

Tags: rigging, unity

As stupid as this sounds, I would like to make a rig with one bone.
The reason why is because said rig doesn't have any actually moving parts, it's just one solid object meant to move on its own. Now the tutorials that I've seen on YouTube and other sources don't seem to provide any information on how to animate a rig that's just a solid object that can roll. I'm using this particular rig for an on-rail shooter in Unity, so I have no idea what to do when it comes to these turns for my player model.
Can anybody lend me a hand here?

Comment: if I get it correctly, if you just use the single bone to move, rotate the other object... it could be quite useless, perhaps... just animate the object, instead of the bone... but maybe there's a missing workflow part  needing this?

Comment: You'll have to add some more information on "that can roll". For something to roll, especially in multiple directions, you will probably need more than one bone.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly you just need to be in object mode with your model, then (SH-A) add an "Armature".  Move it into the model's internals somewhere although that's not absolutely necessary.  Press the X-Ray box in it's properties panel under the "Display" tab so you can see it at all times.

Once scaled and positioned, highlite the bone (select it), get into pose mode (CTL-Tab from Object mode).  Highlite it again if it's not already glowing.  Left click on the model to select that first, then with shift held, left click on the bone.  A 'parent' menu will come up.  Select "Bone".  Your mesh model will then be locked to the bone.

Select the bone not the model when back in Object mode, rotate or move it about and your model will follow.